# NAT and complex bridge configurations

Tags: linux, networking, routing, bridge, nat

I have a complex bridging configuration, which looks like this:

[image]

There is a default route `via 172.31.0.1 dev eth0_bridge`.

Now I'm trying to set up masquerading between `lan_bridge` and `eth0_bridge` so that other devices can connect to `eth1`, get an address from the DHCP server and then access the internet via the default route through `eth0`.

To do this, I'm adding an iptables rule like this:

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.100.0/24 -o eth0_bridge -j MASQUERADE`

Once I've done this (and added the other usual NAT rules - but it's this one that causes trouble) I try to `ping 172.31.0.1` from a client connected to `eth1`.  tcpdump on `172.31.0.1` shows that the packets arrive with their original source address.  It seems this rule is never hit.  So I added a rule like this:

`iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -s 192.168.100.0/24 -j LOG --log-prefix NAT:`

This is the only match that shows up in dmesg:

`[10555.271048] NAT:IN= OUT=eth1_bridge PHYSIN=eth1 PHYSOUT=ve_eth1_lan SRC=192.168.100.210 DST=172.31.0.1 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=55162 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=13662 SEQ=1`

So the only time these packets hit the POSTROUTING table is when they leave `eth1_bridge` to enter the veth pair, heading towards `lan_bridge`.  Sending the packet to MASQUERADE at this point with:

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.100.0/24 -o eth1_bridge -j MASQUERADE`

results in 100% packet loss.

How can I set up NAT between the `192.168.100.0/24` network and the `172.31.0.0/24` network in this scenario?

**Edit** A few more details:

The system where I found this is Alpine 3.9 running a 4.9 kernel.  I've also reproduced it in Ubuntu 18.04 running 4.15, using only two bridges.

Comment: Bonus question: Why is there no `IN` interface in the log message?

Comment: Because the `POSTROUTING` chain doesn't know about input interfaces (much like the `OUTPUT` chain).

Comment: Just trying to understand your configuration: What do you have two bridges with a `veth` patch between them rather than a single bridge?

Comment: Because in practice the setup might be considerably more complicated.  Each bridge in the diagram might be connected to multiple other bridges, each with a different VLAN tagging scheme.  The scheme as shown allows us to flexibly map between VLANs on each port.  But note that there are no VLANs involved in the configuration above and the problem is reproducible on the configuration as shown.

Comment: This is probably a dumb question, but have you enabled ip forwarding (`sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`)?

Comment: Yes, ip_forwarding is enabled.

Comment: But I have an answer for this, will post in a bit.

Comment: Awesome. I added an answer that shows how I've been testing your configuration. Curious to see your answer!

Comment: I created a test setup very similar to the one you describe in your answer.  It didn't really help find the problem, unfortunately.

Comment: I can think of differences in setup: Tom is using legacy iptables with the loaded `br_netfilter` module and sysctl `net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1` which creates interactions between bridge and iptables. See this http://ebtables.netfilter.org/br_fw_ia/br_fw_ia.html#section7 to get what it's about (there's the word ebtables, but ebtables doesn't have to be used at all for this). Now I don't know if it's related. You'd probably have to give all links, addresses, routes, ip rules and iptables-save's output to see if something there could cause a problem

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is only observed with the `br_netfilter` module loaded and iptables enabled on the bridges in question (see `/sys/class/net/*/bridge/nf_call_iptables` and `/proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables` - these are applied as a logical OR, so either you can have it enabled for every bridge on the system or you can enable it for specific bridges, you can't disable it for specific bridges).

With this configuration, the NAT POSTROUTING chain is applied to the packet as it reaches the first bridge.  At this point, the `OUT` device is `eth1_bridge`, as shown in the log message in the question, and so rules with `eth0_bridge` as the output interface don't work.  Setting a too-wide MASQUERADE rule, so that the packet is MASQUERADEd while it is still on `eth1_bridge`, results in MASQUERADEing, but with the wrong source address.

The theoretical solution to this is to disable iptables on bridges system-wide and only enable it where it is actually required.  Sadly, Docker sticks its finger into the pie here and forces (a) the loading of the `br-netfilter` module and (b) setting /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables to 1.  Since we're using docker on this system, it's a bit difficult to fix.  I've raised a bug report on libnetwork for this and intend to submit a patch in the next day or so to fix it.

Comment: This "feature" is activated mostly when in any net ns there's an iptables rule with `-m physdev`. This affects then all other namespaces. If you disable it those rules won't work anymore. SO activating it breaks some rulesets, disabling it breaks other rulesets. Kernel >= 5.3 makes this feature per net ns rather than global. It's also then (don't know which kernel) possible to leave it off and activate it per bridge instead (`ip link set mybridge type bridge nf_call_iptables 1`). Anyway this will probably become obsolete with nftables (which got bridge conntrack support in the same 5.3 kernel)

Comment: There is a `-m physdev` rule on the host where this was originally observed, but it's reproducible on systems without it.

Comment: You have to check this `-m physdev` in all containers. Some containers could have iptables rules

Answer (score 0):

I setup a test environment to attempt to reproduce your problem. The following script sets up three network namespaces to represent three systems:

- The node you have pictured in your question, called `n0`.
- A system `gw` attached to `eth0` with address `173.31.0.1`
- A system `n1` attached to `eth1` with address `192.168.100.100`.

It creates two bridges on the host to represent the 192.168.100.0/24 network and the 173.31.0.0/24 network.

The configuration inside `n0` is as you have described.

```
#!/bin/sh

set -x

ip netns add gw
ip netns add n0
ip netns add n1

ip link add gw-eth0-out type veth peer name gw-eth0-in
ip link add n0-eth0-out type veth peer name n0-eth0-in
ip link add n0-eth1-out type veth peer name n0-eth1-in
ip link add n1-eth0-out type veth peer name n1-eth0-in

brctl addbr 192_168_100
brctl addbr 172_31_0

brctl addif 172_31_0 gw-eth0-out
brctl addif 172_31_0 n0-eth0-out
brctl addif 192_168_100 n0-eth1-out
brctl addif 192_168_100 n1-eth0-out

for iface in 172_31_0 192_168_100 gw-eth0-out n0-eth0-out n0-eth1-out n1-eth0-out; do
    ip link set $iface up
done

ip link set netns gw name eth0 gw-eth0-in
ip link set netns n0 name eth0 n0-eth0-in
ip link set netns n0 name eth1 n0-eth1-in
ip link set netns n1 name eth0 n1-eth0-in

ip netns exec gw ip addr add 172.31.0.1/24 dev eth0
ip netns exec gw ip link set eth0 up

ip netns exec n1 ip addr add 192.168.100.100/24 dev eth0
ip netns exec n1 ip link set eth0 up
ip netns exec n1 ip route add default via 192.168.100.1

ip netns exec n0 brctl addbr eth0_bridge
ip netns exec n0 brctl addbr eth1_bridge
ip netns exec n0 brctl addbr lan_bridge
ip netns exec n0 ip link add patch-eth1 type veth peer name patch-lan

ip netns exec n0 brctl addif eth0_bridge eth0
ip netns exec n0 brctl addif eth1_bridge eth1
ip netns exec n0 brctl addif eth1_bridge patch-lan
ip netns exec n0 brctl addif lan_bridge patch-eth1
ip netns exec n0 ip addr add 172.31.0.10/24 dev eth0_bridge
ip netns exec n0 ip addr add 192.168.100.1/24 dev lan_bridge
for iface in eth0 eth1 eth0_bridge eth1_bridge lan_bridge patch-lan patch-eth1; do
    ip netns exec n0 ip link set $iface up
done
```

When the script finishes running, we have a model of your environment with no `MASQUERADE` rule.  As expected, attempting to ping `172.31.0.1` from `192.168.100.100` will fail.

If we add the masquerade rule to `n0`:

```
ip netns exec n0 iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.100.0/24 -o eth0_bridge -j MASQUERADE
```

The `ping` still fails.

If I enable ip forwarding in `n0`...

```
ip netns exec n0 sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Everything begins to work as expected.